# Recursive function without return - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

Can this be called a recursive function ? It does reduce in one way but not in a *(amount - 1)* type of way...

EDIT:
Also how is it possible to write a recursive function without using return?

```
def wow(amount):
    if amount <= 0:
        print "Don't be so negative!"
    elif amount == 1:
    return "Wow!"
    else:
        return amount * "Wow! \n"



amount = int(raw_input("How many 'Wow!' do you wanna see : "))
print wow(amount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a recursive function. A recursive function has to call itself. [This page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Recursion) explains and shows examples of recursive functions.

This would be a recursive function.

```
def wow(amount):
    if amount <= 0:
        return
    else:
        print("Wow! \n")
        return wow(amount - 1)
```

And a full-fledged solution that turns your code into a recursive function would be.

```
def wow(amount):
    if amount <= 0:
        return "Don't be so negative!"
    elif amount == 1:
        return "Wow!"
    else:
        return inner_wow("", amount)

    def inner_wow(wow_str, amount):
        if amount == 0:
            return
        else:
            wow_str += "Wow! \n"
            return wow(wow_str, amount - 1)
```

In response to your second question. All functions have to return something. Even if you don't tell them to return something they still returns None.